# Calculate average dimensions from a series of image URL's

Tags: javascript, promise

```
// Returns a promise that resolves with the average dimensions of all the passed in images
// Ignores any images that fail to load

function loadImages(images) {
    // Complete the body of this function
    // so that the tests below pass.

}
```

I have tried a lot different way, but it still doesn't work. Anybody can help with that?  I tried map(),reduce().But always get NaN.

Comment: hi XD... topic first with problem statement, followed with problem code, errors and more explanation... End of triage review > requires editing.

Comment: @ZF007 I see. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not gonna attempt to pass your tests but here's a rough example of what you want to do:

- Create a function `loadImage` that "promisifies" the loading of the image. If an image errors out `resolve(null)` so you can filter it out later, when you calculate averages.
- Then [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to ensure all the images are loaded.
- Then [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Filter) to filter out `null`s, which are the errored images.
- Then [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to average the dimensions.

```js
const loadImage = url => {
  const image = new Image()
  image.src = url
  
  return new Promise(res => {
    if (image.complete) return res(image)

    image.onload = () => res(image)
    image.onerror = () => res(null)
  })
}

const getAverageDimsOfImageURLs = imageURLs => {
  return Promise.all(imageURLs.map(loadImage))
    .then(images => {
      // filter out errored images
      images = images.filter(image => image)
    
      return images.reduce((acc, image, index) => {
        acc.width += image.width
        acc.height += image.height
        
        if (index === images.length - 1) {
          acc.width = acc.width / images.length
          acc.height = acc.height / images.length
        }
        
        return acc
      }, {
        width: 0,
        height: 0
      })
     })
}

const imageURLs = [
  'https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-icon.png',
  'http://tineye.com/images/widgets/mona.jpg',
  'http://nonexis2tent.com/images/widgets/mona.jpg' // Bad URL.
]

getAverageDimsOfImageURLs(imageURLs)
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error)
```

Comment: @Nicholas Kyriakides  Thanks a lot, Nik. I will try it.